# References and value affectations : when python does the first and when the secodn

Tags: python

I would like to understand when precisely python affect a variable by value and when by reference.

Take the following example. In this code, I first create a list "dataToTreat", and then I say "dataToTreatBis=dataToTreat". But when I change dataToTreatBis, dataToTreat is not affected.

But in the second part of code, I do the same kind of thing but I change an element of the array dataToTreatBis : dataToTreatBis[0]. And then dataToTreat changes also.

How could I have guessed it ? In both case I work with lists and it is when I change an element of the list that things work by reference and not by new value affectation.

I just would like to understand what is happening : why in the first case I indeed copy the variable but in the second I just change the reference.

```
dataToTreat=[]
for i in (np.arange(5)):
    dataToTreat.append(i)

dataToTreatBis=dataToTreat

print(dataToTreat)
dataToTreatBis=[10,11,12,13,14]
print(dataToTreat) # dataToTreat hasn't changed because of dataToTreatBis

print(" ")
dataToTreat=[]
#data[NdemodB + NdemodA:NdemodB + NdemodA+NtraceA+NtraceB]
for i in range(5):
    dataToTreat.append([0, 1, 2])

dataToTreatBis=dataToTreat

print(dataToTreat[0])
dataToTreatBis[0]=[10,11,12,13,14]
print(dataToTreat[0]) # dataToTreat has changed here !
```

Comment: You misunderstand what a Python variable is. [Read up.](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: It's also important to understand mutable objects, https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable. `=` can do two things - change the object that a name references, and change the contents of a mutable object.

Answer (score 1):

All python variables are bindings to some objects in memory.

In the first part:

```
import numpy as np

dataToTreat=[]
for i in (np.arange(5)):
    dataToTreat.append(i)

dataToTreatBis=dataToTreat

print(dataToTreat)
dataToTreatBis=[10,11,12,13,14]
print 'dataToTreatBis_id: ', id(dataToTreatBis)
print(dataToTreat) # dataToTreat hasn't changed because of dataToTreatBis
print 'dataToTreat_id: ', id(dataToTreat)
```

output:

> dataToTreatBis_id:  85586968
>
> dataToTreat_id:  85586648

In the second part:
    Since you defined a new assignment operator(which is `dataToTreat=[]`) you actually created a new object with a new id.

```
dataToTreat=[]
#data[NdemodB + NdemodA:NdemodB + NdemodA+NtraceA+NtraceB]
for i in (np.arange(5)):
    dataToTreat.append([0, 1, 2])

dataToTreatBis=dataToTreat


print(dataToTreat[0])
dataToTreatBis[0]=[10,11,12,13,14]
print(dataToTreat[0]) # dataToTreat has changed here !
print id(dataToTreatBis)
print id(dataToTreat)
print 'dataToTreatBis_id: ', id(dataToTreatBis)
print 'dataToTreat_id: ', id(dataToTreat)
```

output:

> dataToTreatBis_id:  85586888
>
> dataToTreat_id:  85586888

As you see, you are writing in the same location on memory and that's why the dataToTreat is changing!

Answer (score -1):

Both times, dataToTreatBis is reference to dataToTreat.  However, in first instance you're doing another assignment (completely rewriting) dataToTreatBis and that breaks the linkage.  In second instance, you're just modifying value in one element and thus are not breaking the linkage.  Hope that is clear!